# WPF: Overlapping animations - move a grid behind a toolbar

Tags: wpf, animation

I want to move a window within the main window in wpf. In the example below I want to move the window "moving window" to the top of the main window until it is completely off the main window. I do this with a TranslateTransform.Y animation - the moving window is actually a grid. The problem is, that I want to move the window *behind* the toolbar. Currently if is moved *over* the toolbar. In other words: I want the moving window to disappear behind the toolbar. The toolbar is part of a dock panel, which has a gradient background, the toolbars background is transparent. It doesn't matter what ZIndex I use, the moving window (grid) always moves over the toolbar and is always only cut off by the windows client area (so it "disappears" behind the windows titlebar). How can I achieve such an animation?

```
-------------------------------------------
|              Toolbar                    |
-------------------------------------------
|         -------------------             |
|         |   moving window |             |
|         -------------------             |
|                                         |
-------------------------------------------
```

I created a little quick and dirty Non-MVVM Demo Project to make it clearer. This is the main Window.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MovingWindowTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="SlateGray">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="Debug">
                    <MenuItem Header="Move window in" Click="MoveWindowIn_OnClick" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Move window out" Click="MoveWindowOut_OnClick" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Background="White"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private InnerWindow _InnerWindow;
    private InnerWindow InnerWindow 
    {
        get { return this._InnerWindow ?? ( this._InnerWindow = new InnerWindow() ); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.InnerWindow.Width = this.InnerWindow.Height = 100;
    }

    private void MoveWindowIn_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {            
        Panel.SetZIndex( this.contentGrid, 1 );
        this.InnerWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.contentGrid.Children.Add( this.InnerWindow );
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(-100, 0, new Duration( new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 3 ) ) );
        this.InnerWindow.RenderTransform = trans;
        trans.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim );
    }

    private void MoveWindowOut_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation( 0, -100, new Duration( new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 3 ) ) );
        this.InnerWindow.RenderTransform = trans;
        anim.Completed += ( o, args ) => this.contentGrid.Children.Remove( this.InnerWindow ); ;
        trans.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim );
    }
}
```

The InnerWindow is just a super simple User Control with the following xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MovingWindowTest.InnerWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">TEST</TextBlock>    
</Grid>
```

When the InnderWindow is moved in, it overlaps the Menu, although the menu has a higher ZIndex.
Note that the InnerWindow is added to the contentGrid which is under the menu. And it makes no difference when I add ClipToBounds to the inner window.

Comment: ZIndex behaves differently with elements with in A panel , Their ZIndex is ordered by the way order in which they were arranged,  
could you post some minimalist('ik) xaml to show the DockPanel containing Toolbar and "moving window" , and i'll try to help you.

Comment: I just added an example above.

Comment: I don't understand which part in the dockpanel is the "ToolBar"  
and which part is the "Moving window" please give then names in your XAML so it would be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the parent of the moving window? The DockPanel that also contains the Toolbar or another control? Have you tried setting the ClipToBounds property on the moving window?

Comment: Unfortunately ClipToBounds makes not difference

Comment: Well, adding ClipToBounds to the contentGrid indeed makes the difference!! Thanks a lot!